# Question about the Kolmogorov-Arnold representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

The [Kolmogorov-Arnold representation theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2311185?seq=13#metadata_info_tab_contents) states that any continuous multivariate function $f$ on the unit hypercube can be expressed as

\begin{align}
f(x_1, \cdots, x_m) = \sum_{i=1}^{2m+1} \Phi \left( \sum_{j=1}^m \phi_{i,j}(x_j) \right)
\end{align}

where $\phi_{i,j}$ are continuous monotonically increasing functions on the interval [0,1].

My question is, can this represent any monotonically increasing function $f$ if $\Phi$ is also restricted to be monotonically increasing?

Obviously one way to prove this is to show that given $f$ is increasing, then there exists a corresponding $\Phi$ that is increasing. I think this could be true based on a variant of this theorem known as the [Sprecher construction](http://science.mkoeppen.com/science/uploads/Publications/wstst05.pdf):

\begin{align}
f(x_1, \cdots, x_n) = g \left[ \sum_{j=1}^n h_{p}(x_p) \right]
\end{align}

where all $x_i$ have domain $I$. Sprecher proposes an inner function $h_p$ (remember, the inner functions are independent of $f$) and a method of finding $g$. Essentially, the inner functions map the inputs $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ from base $n$ to a unique value in base $n^n$, creating a bijection between $I^n$ and $I$. Let's call this scalar value $y = \sum_{j=1}^n h_{p}(x_p)$. Finally, $g$ is constructed by simply setting each value in $g$ to the corresponding value in $f$: $g(y) = f\left[h^{-1}(y)\right]$.

It's much easier to prove that there exists a monotonic $g$ for each monotonic $f$ in this alternative representation. We know that the function $h$ is monotonic, so whenever any of the inputs go up, $y$ goes up. Furthermore, if $f$ goes up, then $g$ must go up by the same amount (by its definition). So $g$ must also be monotonic.

Of course, this "proof" is for an alternative form of the representation theorem. Does anyone know how to prove it for the original?

Comment: How do you want to understand $f$ to be monotonic? ie what order do you give the points of the cube?

Comment: $f : \mathbb{R}^m \mapsto \mathbb{R}^1$; so $\forall i$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \geq 0$